# Merging data frames with different time resolution

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, merge

I have two datasets, the first has a 1 second frequency and the second is pretty much random. I want to add the data points from the second data frame into the first one so that I can fit a spline to it and make a pairwise comparison of the two datasets. I have been able to do this by comparing the indexed dates but the computation time is off-the-charts long and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
# GNSS-R data 1 Hz spline fit

# Libraries
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

# Load data
GNSSR_df=read.csv('GNSS-R Oliver.csv')

# Interpolate the GNSS-R data
## Create the 1 sec interval time column
start=as.POSIXct(min(GNSSR_df$date_time))
end=as.POSIXct(max(GNSSR_df$date_time))
date_time=seq(from=start, to=end, by=1)

## Create the new GNSSR data frame
GNSSR_int_df=data.frame('date_time'=date_time, 'wl'=NA)

## Paste the GNSS-R values into the new data frame
n_GNSSR=nrow(GNSSR_df)
for (i in 1:n_GNSSR) {
  GNSSR_int_df$wl[GNSSR_int_df$date_time==GNSSR_df$date_time[i]]=GNSSR_df$WaterLevel.m.[i]}

## Fit a spline to get 1 Hz data
GNSSR_int_df$spline=(NA)
GNSSR_int_df$spline=na.spline(GNSSR_int_df$wl)

## Plot to verify spline fit
plot(GNSSR_int_df$date_time, GNSSR_int_df$wl, xlab='', ylab='Water level (m)', ylim=c(min(GNSSR_int_df$spline), max(GNSSR_int_df$spline)))
lines(GNSSR_int_df$date_time, GNSSR_int_df$spline, type='l', col='forestgreen')
legend('topright', legend=(c('Data', 'Spline')), col=c('black', 'forestgreen'), bty='n', pch=c('o', '-'), inset=0.01)

# Export data to csv
write.csv(GNSSR_int_df, 'GNSS-R, spline fit.csv', row.names = F)
```

Comment: I would think you could bind the rows and then fit your spline taking time into account. Can you include some sample data and the code you are using to fit a spline?

Comment: Can you use `dput` to provide a minimal reproducible example of you data.frames so we can reproduce the problem and test solutions?